# Configuration section for each worker service

Tags: c#, .net, background-service, worker-service

Good day all, I am trying to host two BackgroundService instances in a single IHost and provide them different configuration sections. Unfortunately I cant seem to find a way to do it other than going for the options pattern. here is what my IHost looks like

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostBuilderContext, configurationBuilder) =>
        {
            configurationBuilder.Sources.Clear();
            configurationBuilder.Add(configurationHelperSource);
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostBuilderContext, loggingBuilder) =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
            loggingBuilder.AddProvider(logHelperProvider);
        })
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<ProcessPendingEmails>();
            services.AddHostedService<LoadFilesToDatabase>();
        })
        .Build();

    host.Run();
```

I wish for both of these services to get different IConfiguration sections. Hoping for some help here. Cheers

tried other stackoverflow questions, msdn and I was looking to avoid using the IOptions pattern

Comment: What do you have against the Options Pattern?   Unless you intend to roll your own binary serialisation one JSON config API is pretty much the same as the other.

Comment: I am using a custom configuration provider that loads from database. I just do not want to create data classes for configuration entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .Net Configuration system is based on key and value pairs.  You are not forced to create classes to map individual values if you don't want to.

Simply inject `IConfiguration` and read the configuration values by querying using the key.

From this [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration):

```cs
// Ask the service provider for the configuration abstraction.
IConfiguration config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

// Get values from the config given their key and their target type.
int keyOneValue = config.GetValue<int>("KeyOne");
bool keyTwoValue = config.GetValue<bool>("KeyTwo");
string? keyThreeNestedValue = config.GetValue<string>("KeyThree:Message");
```

Just do the same, except maybe for using `GetRequiredService`.  Instead just ask for `IConfiguration` in the services' constructors.

Comment: Perhaps i was not very clear in my question. I am already reading values the way you've mentioned it. I just want each service to have access to a specific section of the configuration (which is why posted the code segment showing how I am hosting these)

Comment: Ok, I suppose it is possible to inject named dictionaries.  You'll be using IOptions, though.  Is that a deal breaker?  If not, I'll come up with something.  RN I need to run.